# Common model among multiple views

Tags: wpf, mvvm

New to WPF. I have a `Product` model that is an L2S entity. I am creating an application in WPF to edit the product information to potentially replace an old Windows forms app I have. the application has a tab control with a number of tabs on it, such as Packaging, Marketing, Photos, Construction, etc.

My question is how do I structure this in a MVVM system. Do I have a separate view for each tab, each with it's own view model relating to it's particular subset of the `Product` model? Or do I have a single view with the tab control and all of the fields and a single view model to encompass the model in it's entirety? Or am I going about it completely wrong?

I feel like the first option is the way to go, but then I am also unsure of how to share the same model across multiple view models. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

--Edit--

Examples of data on the pages:
Marketing has several text fields, and a few subset entity collections such as features, applications, and cross references.
Photos handles a collection of Photos for the product
Packaging and Construction are each a large collection of text fields/combos/checkboxes related to their respective information in the Product

Comment: It is hard to say without info about what is represented on each tab? `Marketing, Photos, Construction`?

Comment: Some people will create a ViewModelBase with a PackagingViewModel, MarketingViewModel, etc which all inherit ViewModelBase.  I'd say start implementing one of the ViewModels, then implement another.  Then, refactor the common properties into ViewModelBase accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

With  this minimum of info you've provided I would suggest following solution:

1. Main `ProductView` view
2. Separate View for the each tab
3. Main container ViewModel: ProductViewModel
4. For complex tabs separate view model as well. For instance you would have a separate `PackagingViewModel` so `ProductViewModel` should expose `public PackagingViewModel Packaging` property
5. `ProductViewModel` should accept all model-related stuff (perhaps some services, model entity, etc) and then initialize all other child view models.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still a bit confused. I expose all of the tab view models via properties in the `ProductViewModel` and hook it up to the `ProductView`. How do the tab views see the properties of their parent's view model? Aren't the child views ignorant of their parent view's data context?